# Hide database from other users in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have created a database in SQL Server 2008 and it shows in server object explorer to all users that can login to SQL.

I want to hide it from those users, I want it to be viewable by me only.

How can I do that? Any help, suggestions?

Many thanks

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot do this in SQL Server Management Studio. Everyone sees all databases - whether they can use anything inside them or not.

Comment: Just because they can see it, it doesn't mean they can access it. If you need to hide the existence of a database from other users, use a separate server (or instance)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setup a SQL Server database that's only visible to certain users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799812/setup-a-sql-server-database-thats-only-visible-to-certain-users)

Answer (score 6):

Try this: In SQL Server Management Studio, right click the server and click "Properties".
Click on "Permissions" and then select the "Public" role and remove "Grant" from "View Any Database".

Answer (score 0):

USE master;
GO

DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO [loginname]; 
GO

USE [your db];
GO

DROP USER [loginname];
GO

USE master;
GO

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[your db]TO [loginname];
GO

Answer (score 0):

DbDefence can hide database schema from anyone including DBA.
It's completely free for SQL Server 2008 without limits.

*I'm associated with the vendor. Hope its not advertising because the product is free.*